# Check if string is a valid date, and if it is, whether it is in a specific range

Tags: c#, .net, validation, datetime

So i'm trying to validate date in format DDMMYYYY.

```
string date = "12031996";
```

i want to be able to validate if what user entered is in this specific format. And also want to be able to check if the year is in range of 1980 - 2005.

I'm new to C# so please forgive if it sounds like a stupid question.
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you not done any research? This is a very straightforward issue. Have you thought about breaking it down into individual steps and researching how to do each step?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO).  SO is not a forum, it's actually a Question and Answer site.  That being the case, your first course of action should be to search for answers before attempting to ask a question.  Secondly, questions should be specific in a way that there is only 1 actual question.  Your question is actually 2 and should be broken down as such.

Comment: Before asking more question please take a moment to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it will increase your chances of either finding and answer or asking it in a way that it can be answer quickly.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "ddMMyyyy", NULL, DateTimeStyle.None, out DateTime dateTime))
{
    int year = dateTime.Year;
    if (year >= 1980 && year <= 2005)
        //do something if in range
    else
        //do something otherwise
}
else
    //do something for invalid format.
```

To learn more about how to parse a date time string in C#, read this [page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: There's a catch here. An exception will occur if the date is like "1231996".

Comment: Yeah, change to TryParseExact

Comment: Please don't answer questions that haven't shown any attempt at solving the issue.

Comment: This is ok now. Good response !!

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)